# Get all registered country code top-level domain names

Tags: domains, top-level-domains

Is there a way to get all the registered domain names for .CN or another country code (CC) top-level domain (TLD)?

Is there a central registry for such data?  If not, how do I go about collecting them?

Answer (score 4):

You will need permission from the owner of the root zone for the Top-Level Domain (TLD)  to acquire a copy of the root zone.

The [IANA Root Zone Database](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/) lists owners for different TLD's if you'd like to follow up (some may require that you have a verifiable academic or business interest in the information).

As an example, Verisign maintains an FAQ for those interested in [downloading the .COM, .NET, and .NAME zone files](http://www.verisigninc.com/en_US/products-and-services/domain-name-services/grow-your-domain-name-business/analyze/tld-zone-access/index.xhtml) (with daily updates).